# how to remove unwanted characters in php webpage? i'm getting like "; "; "; characters by following code

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM spray_chart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['date1']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['operator_name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['equipment']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['bio_chem_name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['appl_rate_ml']; ?></td>";
               <td><?php echo $row['beds']; ?></td>";
               <td><?php echo $row['comment1']; ?></td>";
            </tr>
        </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: You have got "; behind your closing td-tags. You dont happen to mean that, do you?

Comment: The problem you describe is the browser handling the (malformed) HTML your PHP is delivering.

Comment: @evayly yes right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><?php echo $row['appl_rate_ml']; ?></td>";
<td><?php echo $row['beds']; ?></td>";
<td><?php echo $row['comment1']; ?></td>";
```

These three lines have an extra `";` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM spray_chart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['date1']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['operator_name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['equipment']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['bio_chem_name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['appl_rate_ml']; ?></td>"
               <td><?php echo $row['beds']; ?></td>"
               <td><?php echo $row['comment1']; ?></td>"
            </tr>
        </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```